# How can I find indexes with same elements in 2d numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm working on a machine vision project. By reflecting laser light on the picture, I detect the pixels that the laser light falls on the picture with the help of Opencv. I keep these pixel values ​​as 2d numpy array. However, I want to make the x, y values ​​unique by determining the pixel values ​​whose x axis values ​​are the same and taking the average of them. Pixel values ​​are kept sequentially in numpy array.

For example:

```
[[659 253]
 [660 253]
 [660 256]
 [661 253]
 [662 253]
 [663 253]
 [664 253]
 [665 253]]
```

First of all, my goal is to identify all lists in which the first element of each list is the same. When using Opencv, pixel values ​​are kept in numpy arrays to be more useful. I'm trying to write an indexing method myself. I created a numpy array for myself to make it simpler.

```py
x = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 78], [1, 3], [1, 6], [4, 3], [5, 6], [5, 3]], np.int32)
```

I followed a method like this to find the values ​​whose first element is the same from the lists in the x array.

```
for i in range (len (x)):
        if x [i]! = x [-1] and x [i] [0] == x [i + 1] [0]:
            print (x [i], x [i + 1])
```

I want to check if the first element in the first list is in the next lists by browsing the x array list. In order not to face an index out of range error, I used `x [i]!  = x [-1]`. I was expecting this loop to return below result to me.

```
[1,2] [1,78]
[1,78] [1,3]
[1,3] [1,6]
[5,6] [5,3]
```

I would later remove duplicate elements from the list but I got

> **ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.Use a.any() or a.all()**

I am not familiar with numpy arrays so I could not get the solution I wanted. Is it possible to get the result I want using numpy array methods? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Show the methods you use to get that error.

Comment: I am asking numpy array methods. Not python methods. I didn't use any numpy array methods.

Comment: Can you please show what you did to get the error? It will help me help you solve this. It's also generally good practice and common courtesy. It doesn't have to be anything fancy. I just want to know where your head is at so to speak.

Comment: I just try this. 
for i in range(len(x)):
    if x[i] != x[-1] and x[i][0] == x[i+1][0]:
        print(x[i], x[i+1])

Comment: I've drafted an answer. I'll post it once you've [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64249718/edit) the post.

Comment: Also, can you please include a stack trace that indicates the line of the error, and explain what you think `if x[i] != x[-1]` is doing?

Comment: In case you are wondering why I am bugging you about this: SO is a site for people to look up problems that they encountered, much more that just for you to get help on your personal question. We try to encourage users to get in the habit of making complete questions that are useful for future readers.

Comment: I can understand, you are right about this. However, at first I gave such an answer because you made the warning harshly. I will explain the question more clearly and with the methods that I use.

Comment: My apologies for the harshness. Most new users are here to get free codez, so I doubly appreciate your responsiveness

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach 1**

This is a numpy way to do this:

```
x_sorted = x[np.argsort(x[:,0])]
marker_idx = np.flatnonzero(np.diff(x_sorted[:,0]))+1
output = np.split(x_sorted, marker_idx)
```

**Approach 2**

You can also use a package `numpy_indexed` which is designed to solve groupby problems with less script and without loss of performance:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
npi.group_by(x[:, 0]).split(x)
```

**Approach 3**

You can get groups of indices but this might not be the best option because of list comprehension:

```
import pandas as pd
[x[idx] for idx in pd.DataFrame(x).groupby([0]).indices.values()]
```

**Output**

```
[array([[  1,   2],
       [  1,  78],
       [  1,   3],
       [  1,   6],
       [  1, 234]]), 
array([[4, 3]]), 
array([[5, 6],
       [5, 3]])]
```

Comment: I have reached the result what I want with approach1. The work of  np.flatnonzero (np.diff (x_sorted [:, 0])) + 1 line is great. I would have wasted a lot of time here without your help. Thank you so much. I will mark this answer as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, using itertools.groupby:

```
x.sort(axis=0)
for l in [list([tuple(p) for p in k]) for i,k in itertools.groupby(x, key=lambda x: x[0])]:
    print(l)
```

Output:

```
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6)]
[(3, 6), (3, 78)]
[(5, 234)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`np.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) with its `return_inverse` argument, which is effectively a sorting index, and `return_counts`, which is going to help build the split points:

```
_, ind, cnt = np.unique(x[:, 0], return_index=True, return_counts=True)
```

The index `i` arranges `u` into `x`. To sort the other way, you need to invert the index. Luckily, [`np.argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) is its own inverse:

```
ind = np.argsort(ind)
```

To get the splitpoints of the data, you can use [`np.cumsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) on the count. You don't need the last element because it is always going to mark the end of the array:

```
spp = np.cumsum(cnt[:-1])
```

Finally, you can use `np.split` to get the list of sub-arrays that you want:

```
result = np.split(x[ind, :], spp, axis=0)
```

**TL;DR**

```
_, ind, cnt = np.unique(x[:, 0], return_index=True, return_counts=True)
np.split(x[np.argsort(ind), :], np.cumsum(cnt[:-1]), axis=0)
```